# Open new chrome tab from Terminal

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, cmd.exe

If I were to type `start http://facebook.com` a new chrome tab will open and point to Facebook but

When I type in `start chrome://newtab` into cmd I get the following error message

"You'll need a new app to open this chrome link."

It then prompts me to Look for an app in the Microsoft store. There are no apps in the store that support the link and it does not let me choose from a list of programs. I was wondering if there is any way that a new chrome tab can be opened on windows from terminal.

TLDR:

`start "URL"` opens new tab pointed to URL in Chrome

`start "chrome://newtab"` asks for an app to open chrome link

I want `start "chrome://newtab"` to open a new tab in active chrome window

Comment: Have you installed chrome? Is it in your Windows PATH? Is it your default browser?

Comment: Both are positive. The issue is that "chrome://newtab" is not recognized as a URL

Comment: `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome://newtab` works for me. You must have the empty quotes as the first perameter to `start` is the Window title ...

Comment: This works and I may just be picky at this point but it opens a new windows as opposed to a new tab is there anyway it can open a newtab instead? Does it open a newtab for you?

Comment: @AriDokmecian Yes, just use `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome://newtab "https://facebook.com"` for example. Pass the URL to open after the `chrome://newtab` argument.

Comment: `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome://newtab "https://facebook.com"`

Comment: This opens up facebook in a new tab. I want it to open to the new tab page which is located at chrome://newtab.